# Running python from CMD - fails due to wrong understanding of imports

Tags: python, command-line

I implemented a python main script.

When I run it from the PyCharm environment everything is working fine.

However, if I run the script from distant directory I got errors.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from module1.object_loader import ObjectLoader

if __name__ == '__main__':
   parameters = sys.argv
   record_features = parameters[1]

   object_loader = ObjectLoader()
```

The object loader is not recognized.

I succeeded to run it when I put all the functions of the ObjectLoader into the main script.

Is there any way to solve it more elegantly? OOP?

Comment: so are you running your cmd in directory where ObjectLoade.py is stored?

Comment: `print sys.path` to check if module1 in your exec path

Comment: This import `module1.object_loader import ObjectLoader` will work if there is a directory named `module1` in a directory which is in [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) and there are files named `__init__.py` and `object_loader.py` in that directory and there is a class named `ObjectLoader` in `object_loader.py` and nothing fails. What is the error?